# Is there a file selection widget for ipywidgets that works remotely?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I found this beautiful implementation of a Qt [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162920/file-selection-button-for-jupyter-notebook)
Unfortunately, that does not work when the notebook is not local. I wonder whether anyone knows an implementation that works also in remote notebooks.

Comment: No one knows. No, no, no.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have a look into the [ipyvuetify FileInput component](https://github.com/mariobuikhuizen/ipyvuetify/blob/master/examples/extra/FileInput.ipynb)

I use it on a remote notebook and it works like a charm

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipyvuetify.extra import FileInput
import hashlib

file_input = FileInput()
file_input

myfiles = file_input.get_files()
myfiles[0]
```

you can then do whatever you want with the content of myfiles (upload, modify, copy... etc)

Comment: Just heard about this in a talk. It looks very promissing.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this posted in ipywidgets gitter a few weeks ago, not my code. Any use?

https://gitlab.com/oscar6echo/ipyupload