# jupyter widgets - file upload - unable to read file in databricks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, databricks, ipywidgets, ipyvuetify

I'm trying to use a jupyter file upload widget (ipywidgets/ipyvuetify..) to read a file from my local machine in a databricks notebook.

I considered ipywidgets, but databricks doesn't seem to support the file upload feature in ipywidgets - https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/ipywidgets.html#limitations

I found another widget library called ipyvuetify.

This is the code I tried. Picking the file works as expected.

```
from ipyvuetify.extra import FileInput
file_input = FileInput()
file_input
```

```
files = file_input.get_files()
data = files[0]['file_obj'].read()
data
```

I get this timeout exception when I try the read() above -

```
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-2037501063098494>:1
----> 1 data = files[0]['file_obj'].read()
      2 data

File /lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipyvuetify/extra/file_input.py:147, in ClientSideFile.readall(self)
    146 def readall(self):
--> 147     return self.read(self.size - self.offset)

File /lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipyvuetify/extra/file_input.py:143, in ClientSideFile.readinto(self, buffer)
    140         self.widget.update_stats(self.file_index, chunk_size)
    141         await process_messages()
--> 143 asyncio.run(read_all())
    144 return size

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nest_asyncio.py:35, in _patch_asyncio.<locals>.run(main, debug)
     33 task = asyncio.ensure_future(main)
     34 try:
```

Other related stackoverflow question -
[ipyvuetify file selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54484376/is-there-a-file-selection-widget-for-ipywidgets-that-works-remotely)

github issue -
[file upload widget](https://github.com/widgetti/ipyvuetify/issues/50#issuecomment-922037522)

Would really appreciate any input solving this, or if anyone has done something similar in databricks.

Comment: Could you solve this problem? I suspect the problem may be the same in both libraries: the websocket_max_message_size config. I'm also trying to use the ipyvuetify library as I could not change websocket_max_message_size config when using voila.